# below code gives only enable value i want both enable and disable all product in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, product, database, eav, disabled-products

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');


$collection = $productCollection->create()

            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setPageSize(3) //Selecting 3 products
            ->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){  
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getStatus().'<br>';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try the below solution:**

```
$collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, its working.

Comment: Hii madani,
can u plz tell me how to merge 2 Product collection,
{{ $_productCollection = merge_collections($Collection1,$Collection2); }}

i tried this one but this is not working.

Comment: Try this one:
 $_productCollection = array_merge($Collection1->getData(),$Collection2->getData());

           OR

 $_productCollection = array_merge($Collection1,$Collection2;